# Accounts on SE sites does not appear on my SE Accounts tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, user-accounts

Every time I visit my SE network profile and click on the Accounts tab, it shows only four accounts, namely: Ask Ubuntu, Unix and Linux, Meta Stack Overflow and Area 51.

[image]

However, I do have a total of 7 accounts on the SE network as shown in my AU profile:

[image]

But, when I click on the view more link, it shows the same four accounts on SE.

---

Also, in my SU account profile, it says that I have **0** other accounts in SE:

[image]

Is this a bug? I just want to be able to view all my accounts across SE on all of my accounts' profiles.

Hope someone could fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, that Ask Ubuntu visited link color is confusing. Makes it look like it's not even a link anymore... I spent a minute wondering "how does one get a plain-text account listed there?"

Comment: :)) I think visited links on AU has an orange color, plain black for *not yet clicked* links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A merge went very sideways here, leaving users on the new and old account.  I manually fixed up your account associations and you should be all set now.